# Bipartite graph to a projection graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, bipartite, graph-neural-network

Hi I'm trying to project a bipartite graph (B) using Networkx's projected_graph but due to memory constraints (B has more than 140K nodes), this keeps crashing. I tried a matrix multiplication using a sparse matrix for computing the adjacency matrix but due to my matrix not being sparse enough, that didn't work either. Can anyone please help with this?

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

B.add_nodes_from(inmates_list, bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(cells_list, bipartite=1)

inmates = set(n for n,d in B.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite']==0)
cells = = set(B) - inmates
G = bipartite.projected_graph(B, inmates)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# Assuming your DataFrame is named 'df' with n rows and k columns for labels

# Create an empty graph
graph = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes to the graph
graph.add_nodes_from(df.index)

# Create a dictionary to store the weights for each pair of nodes
weights = {}

# Iterate over the labels and update the weights based on the count of common labels
for label in df.columns:
    label_nodes = df.index[df[label] == 1].tolist()
    edges = [(u, v) for u, v in nx.utils.pairwise(label_nodes)]
    
    # Update the weights for each edge
    for u, v in edges:
        if (u, v) in weights:
            weights[(u, v)] += (df.loc[u, label].astype(bool) & df.loc[v, label].astype(bool)).sum()
        else:
            weights[(u, v)] = (df.loc[u, label].astype(bool) & df.loc[v, label].astype(bool)).sum()

# Add the edges with updated weights to the graph
graph.add_weighted_edges_from((u, v, weight) for (u, v), weight in weights.items())

# Now you have the graph with weighted edges based on the count of common labels
```